# Offline Sonar analysis to signal a broken build

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Sonar analysis is a nice way to check code compliance against a centrally defined policy. This is why I would like to use a profile with Blocker a Critical rules to signify a broken build.

I am using Jenkins do builds and invoke the SonarRunnerBuilder to get standard analysis on nightly builds of projects.

To achieve the features I outlined it would be best if I could run the analysis, check the results for violations (preferrably not sending them to Sonar server) and fail the build if there were any violations. So far I have not found way to do this using Google and looking through SonarRunner source code.

What I have considered is a workaround. I would implement a [Decorator](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Coding+a+Plugin#CodingaPlugin-Decorator) collecting violations and when the decoration reaches the project resource I would throw a RuntimeException to break the analysis. This would in turn fail the build.

would this work? Is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for seems to be what the [build breaker plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/integration/build-breaker/) offers. It relies on the Quality gate configuration to detect when violations (now called issues) in the current analysis require to break the whole build.

Please consider that this plugin won't be supported in SonarQube 5.2. Technically, deep changes in SonarQube's architecture make it impossible to provide the same feature. Philosophically, this plugin does not match the experience SonarQube wants to offer.

Still, another solution which covers the same use case is very likely to be offered in future version of SonarQube but this is yet to be defined.

Comment: So before we move from 5.0 to 5.2 I still can:
* use build breaker - to break the build
* choose a different Quality profile - to filter rules (just blocker and criticals)
* use sonar.issuesReport.html - to have a list to show
* run the analysis in preview mode - to avoid submitting results

I wondered - does my usecase "match the experience SonarQube wants to offer"?

How will I be able to filter the rules to run after 5.0 when I can't choose a different profile?

What technical limitations prevent build breaker from working in 5.2?

Thanks for your advice

Comment: * almost-quoting someone: "Yes, you can". * Long story short: in the experience SonarSource wants to offer, the developer won't even commit the issue in the first place. To give you a taste of what might be coming: many tools will be put in the developer's hands to achieve vision. One on which is simulating the analysis of the project including its commit and see if it would break the Quality Gate.